# Can one with a poor diet gain muscle if they work out?

Tags: diet, muscle-gain

My diet is healthy, but I am wondering just for the heck of it if a person with an unhealthy diet that lifts weights can still make gains in muscle mass or not. That is my question. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, they will gain muscles because they're lifting weight. If they're eating protein food, they'll gain muscles also. However, because of the unclean diet, they'll probably gain much fat, which will prevent the muscles from being very visible.

Answer (score 3):

Healthy is a fuzzy term. It probably doesn't matter much if you eat trans fats, big macs and protein bars or salads, quinoa and turkey, assuming that the macro nutrient amounts are equal.

What does matter is the amount of protein. Also, eating healthy, if it really is healthy, will make you live better and longer.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get some muscle with a poor diet, but it will probably be slow, with high fat precent and not the full capacity of the body. Eating good is a vital thing to fully develop your body.

Answer (score 1):

You most certainly CAN build muscle on a sub-optimal diet. One way to think about this : there are two men , with virtually identical physiques. One decides to eat a very high protein diet , but does no training. The other sticks to his "average" diet , makes no changes at all to his eating patterns , but does an intense full-body weights workout , 2-3 times a week. After a year , who will have the better developed physique ? Bet the house on the second man.